# What causes error java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate nrepl/server__init.class or nrepl/server.clj on classpath on boot?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

When I try to launch boot with my Clojure project I get the following error:

```
PS F:\osob\Clojure\modern-cljs> boot serve -d target watch reload cljs target
Starting reload server on ws://localhost:55343
                                       java.lang.Thread.run
         java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
          java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
                        java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run
                                                        ...
                        clojure.core/binding-conveyor-fn/fn                     core.clj: 1916
                                          boot.core/boot/fn                     core.clj: 1031
                         
;skipped some text


                                       clojure.core/load/fn                     core.clj: 5866
                                                        ...
          java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate nrepl/server__init.class or nrepl/server.clj on classpath.
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate nrepl/server__init.class or nrepl/server.clj on classpath., compiling:(boot/repl_server.clj:1:1)
             clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate nrepl/server__init.class or nrepl/server.clj on classpath., compiling:(boot/repl_server.clj:1:1)
    line: 15
```

I had the following deps:

```
 :dependencies '[[adzerk/boot-cljs "1.7.228-2"]
                 [pandeiro/boot-http "0.7.6"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]
                 [adzerk/boot-reload "0.5.1"]]) ;; add boot-reload

(require '[adzerk.boot-cljs :refer [cljs]]
         '[pandeiro.boot-http :refer [serve]]
         '[adzerk.boot-reload :refer [reload]]) ;; make reload visible
```

The problem is caused nrepl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing `[pandeiro/boot-http "0.7.6"]` to `[pandeiro/boot-http "0.7.5"]` solved the issue.

Comment: `org.clojure/tools.nrepl` is an extremely old version and the namespaces all changed shortly after it moved to `nrepl/nrepl` -- which the more recent version of `boot-http` expects. That's why downgrading that library made it work. But you'll need to be careful because a lot of editor tooling assumes the new version of nREPL these days.

Comment: so I should use nrepl/nrepl?

Comment: I think that updating all your dependencies and switching to `nrepl/nrepl` will make life easier for you, yes.